# Doubtes in MS KB Numbers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, patch-management

I am having some doubtes in MS KB numbers, For Example MS16-103 (KB 3182332) - under this we have two different KB nos like 3176492, 3176493. My doubts is which one we should apply in the server.

in server kb 3176493 is installed, this kb is under ms16-103.  now the user is asking MS16-103 (KB 3182332) is installed of no. if i search in this no ( get-hotfix -d "KB" ) it says its not installed but if i search 3176493 this no kb is installed. so which one is applicable. now how i can check   MS16-103 (KB 3182332) this kb is installed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in add/remove program under the update section.

or use the powershell command Get-Hotfix with no parameter and check the KB list.

[image]

For the KB you listed, they are not applicable to Windows 2008-R2.

Under the KB3182332's text (that link to the MS16-103) you see the two OS that is affected by it; and two cumulative KB that affect those two different OS, but that solve KB3182332.

Windows 10 build 1511 and Windows 10.

Quote from [there](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3182332):

- For all supported 32-bit editions of **Windows 10**:
  Windows10.0-**KB3176492**-x86.msu
- For all supported x64-based editions of **Windows 10**: Windows10.0-**KB3176492**-x64.msu
- For all supported 32-bit editions of **Windows 10 Version 1511**: Windows10.0-**KB3176493**-x86.msu
- For all supported x64-based editions of **Windows 10 Version 1511**: Windows10.0-**KB3176493**-x64.msu

Comment: yes i can see but what is the different between MS16-103 (KB 3182332)-under this we have two different KB nos like 3176492, 3176493

Comment: oh, will update my answer, I now see more what is your problem